# Treeview does not refresh to show childnode moved from one parent node to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I am using the Windows Forms `TreeView` class which contains a set of `TreeNode`s. The `TreeNode`s can have child nodes.

I have a root node with 2 sub nodes (Node1 and Node2)

Node1 has 2 subnodes (child1 and child2)

I have a function that will allow a user to select any node and move it to another node:

```
TreeNode SelectNode = this.TreeView1.SelectedNode;
TreeNode DestNode = SelectedNewNode();  //function to select a new node
SelectedNode.Remove();
DestNode.Nodes.Add(SelectedNode);
this.TreeView1.Refresh();
```

When this executes, the current selected node (child2) is removed from its current parent 
(Node1) and added to Node2.

However, the `Refresh()` method of the `TreeView` control does not show that child2 is under Node2.  If I debug it and look at the `Nodes` collection in the `TreeView` i do see that child2 is under Node2.

Can anyone tell me why the `Refresh()` method does not redraw the new parent to child mapping?
Is there a way to tell the `TreeView` to redraw with the new mappings?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is just a typo or not, but in the first line you refer to `SelectNode` and then you later add something called `SelectedNode`.  These might be referring to different variables/properties.

Otherwise, there is either a problem with your `SelectedNewNode` function, or this code is being executed in some long-running synchronous operation and no repaints are happening at all.  You don't need the `Refresh` method at all; when you invoke the `Remove()` method on a `TreeNode`, the display will be updated, and when you `Add` it to another parent, it will be updated again.  Remove the `Refresh` call.

If you are indeed trying to update during a long-running operation, then you need to invoke `Invalidate` followed by `Update`.  However, if this isn't in a loop or blocking call somewhere, that's going to be pointless.

There's one other possibility, which is that you've invoked the `TreeView.BeginUpdate` method and forgotten to invoke `TreeView.EndUpdate`, which would prevent any updates from being displayed.

Just to test this out, I tested this on a new Windows Form with a `TreeView` added two roots (`Node0` and `Node1`) and one child to each (`Node2` and `Node3`).  The following code successfully updates the display of the `TreeView`:

```
TreeNode nodeToMove = treeView1.Nodes.Find("Node3", true).First();
TreeNode newParent = treeView1.Nodes.Find("Node0", false).First();
nodeToMove.Remove();
newParent.Nodes.Add(nodeToMove);
```

If none of the above suggestions solve your problem, then start from this working example and look at the difference between the working example and your current code.

Comment: It was a typo in the post it should be SelectNode. I do not invoke the BeginUpdate method before the child node is removed and added to the new parent. I've ended up clearing the nodes collection in the treeview and then recreating it.  that seems to work.